# How to insert Object as a item of panel

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extjs, extjs3

I have to insert object as a item of Panel. I created object and in Panel I place item as a array. Then how to add that object into items of array.

My Code :

```
{
    title : "Records",
    bodyStyle: 'background: #dfe8f6;border:#dfe8f6;',
    autoScroll: true,
    id:'ExcludeRecord',
    region: 'center',
    layout:{
        type: 'vbox',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items:  [],
    }`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to add an item to the panel:

```
var panel = Ext.getCmp('ExcludeRecord');
panel.add(object);   // Your object.
panel.doLayout();
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Shall I write this in any `beforerender` or `afterrender` function or in `initComponent` function.

Comment: Yes you can write in any of them function but you must have these object in that function.      
  Ext.apply(me, {
            items      :  [{object}],
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
You can use above code in initComponent to directly that object as item.

Comment: For multiple record I am using `for` loop. Then `panel.doLayout()` is supposed to inside for loop right. In that case only one time object is appearing.

Comment: This is fine for one record, but for multiple record this is not adding.

Comment: If you are adding  item in loop then must take care of that you do not have to use id as config property for that object. You can use itemId and try to put this value unique for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can put object in items array

```
{
    title : "Records",
    bodyStyle: 'background: #dfe8f6;border:#dfe8f6;',
    autoScroll: true,
    id:'ExcludeRecord',
    region: 'center',
    layout:{
        type: 'vbox',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items:  [{
           xtype:'panel',
           html:'Your Object'
            }],
    }
```